# change <audio> src with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have multiple audio files that I want to stream based on the user selects. How do I do that? This is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to work.

*UPDATE: Made a few changes and now its claiming that `audio.load();` is not a function. Can anyone tell me why that is? The Code is updated to reflect the changes.

JavaScript:

```
function updateSource(){ 
    var audio = document.getElementById('oggSource');
    audio.src = 
        'audio/ogg/' + 
        document.getElementById('song1').getAttribute('data-value');
    audio.load();
}
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
    <source id="oggSource" src="" type="audio/ogg"></source>
    <source id="mp3Source" type="audio/mp3"></source>
        Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>

<ul style="list-style: none">
    <li>Sunday May 27, 2012
        <ul style="display: none">
            <li id="song1" data-value="song1.ogg">
                <button onclick="updateSource();">Item1</button>
            </li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`Item2` and `Item3` I will want to play a different audio file when they are clicked on.

Comment: You have to *play* it after you load the media. `audio.play`.

Comment: @Derek That did it! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Now is there a way to make the media player show up? It stays hidden for some reason.

Comment: Take a look at my comment below.

Comment: i tried doing <audio src="dropbox/link/ahc.mp3"> and it does work...any idea why?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Try this snippet

```js
list.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var elm = e.target;
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

  var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
  source.src = elm.getAttribute('data-value');

  audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
  audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
};
```

```html
<ul style="list-style: none">
  <li>Audio Files
    <ul id="list">
      <li><a href="#" data-value="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga">Death_Becomes_Fur.oga</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4">Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="http://media.w3.org/2010/11/rrs006.oga">rrs006.oga</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sound/sound_90.mp3">sound_90.mp3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
  Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jm6ky/2/

Comment: Now it complains that `source` is null. So it doesn't even get to the `audio.load()`

Comment: Nevermind, `source` was null because I mispelled the id in one place. But now it doesn't do anything. Firebug doesn't show any errors but it still isn't working. Not sure why.

Comment: Yeah I am using your example. I just had to add `audio.play()` after I loaded the file. Now it plays the music, but I'd like the media player to show up, for some reason it stays hidden.

Comment: The player UI is different for each browser, in safari I can see a little black player. I'm not sure if firefox add a UI to the audio tag, but You can do the player UI yourself, and add buttons to `player.play()` `player.pause()` etc... including sliders and time stamp

Comment: I realize it's different for each browser. It just seems odd that it only shows up in FF once the song ends, but shows up fine from the beginning in other browsers. I've never made a player UI myself, but it might be something I try to do.

Comment: Angular example: 

 var video = angular.element('#audio');
        
        if (audio){
            audio.load();
        }

Comment: `Audio.load()` triggers a render loop when adapted to libs like React.

Answer (score 4):

with jQuery:

```
 $("#playerSource").attr("src", "new_src");

    var audio = $("#player");      

    audio[0].pause();
    audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element

    if (isAutoplay) 
        audio[0].play();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are storing metadata in a tag use data attributes eg.

```
<li id="song1" data-value="song1.ogg"><button onclick="updateSource()">Item1</button></li>
```

Now use the attribute to get the name of the song

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
audio.src='audio/ogg/' + document.getElementById('song1').getAttribute('data-value');
audio.load();
```

Comment: FF and Chrome are now saying that `audio.load()` is not a function. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Fourthmeal70 Post your updated code so we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Found [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) spec note for those trying to change the src of a source element. Especially useful for libs like React where `audio.load()` **causes render loop**.

> ..modifying a source element and its attribute when the element is
> already inserted in a video or audio element will have no effect. To
> change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the media
> element directly

```
<audio>
    <source src='./first-src'/>
</audio>
```

To change the src

```
<audio src='./second-src'/>
    <source src='./first-src'/>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it using React and CJSX (Coffee JSX) based on *Vitim.us* solution.
Using `componentWillReceiveProps` I was able to detect every property changes. Then I just check whether the url has changed between the future props and the current one. And voilà.

```
@propTypes =
    element: React.PropTypes.shape({
         version: React.PropTypes.number
         params:
             React.PropTypes.shape(
                 url: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
                 filename: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
                 title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
                 ext: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
             ).isRequired
     }).isRequired

componentWillReceiveProps: (nextProps) ->
    element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    audio = element.querySelector('audio')
    source = audio.querySelector('source')

    # When the url changes, we refresh the component manually so it reloads the loaded file
    if nextProps.element.params?.filename? and
    nextProps.element.params.url isnt @props.element.params.url
        source.src = nextProps.element.params.url
        audio.load()
```

I had to do it this way, because even a change of state or a force redraw didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

Replace:

```
audio.load();
```

with:

```
audio.play();
```

Comment: I had to do both. Its working now but how to I make it so the media player show up?

Comment: [`<audio controls src=""></audio>`](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cs2Lw/) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Audio)

Comment: Adding `src=""` there makes it stop working. Firebug says its getting an invalid URI. But when `src=""` is not there it plays the song fine.

Comment: No no no, that `src` is just an example! You don't need to follow it. All I mean is that `controls`.

Comment: Oh! That was the only difference between what I already had and your example. I have `controls` there and it still does not show up.

Comment: Actually it shows up fine in Chrome. In FF it shows up once the song ends but not when it first starts.. Any Ideas?

Comment: Hmm... It works on my Firefox though. (maybe it is some where in your page you didn't notice)

Comment: Not that I see.. I guess I'll have to play around with it. My main issue has been resolved though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you need to wait for the new media to load before starting the audio. To do this, use the loadeddata event as below:

Vue 3

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const srcaudio = ref("");
    
    const playMusic = (url) => {
        srcaudio.value = url
        const audioplay = document.getElementById("audioplay"); // audio element
    
        audioplay.load(); //preload
        audioplay.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
             audioplay.play(); //playing
        });
    };
</script>
<template>
        <audio id="audioplay" :src="srcaudio"></audio>
        <button @click.prevent="playMusic('/music-url.mp3')">Play</button>
</template>
```

HTML/JavaScript

```
<body>
        <audio id="audioplay"></audio>
        <button id="playbutton">Play</button>
        <script>
             const playbutton = document.getElementById("playbutton"); // button element
             const audioplay = document.getElementById("audioplay"); // audio element

             playbutton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                 audioplay.src = '/music-url.mp3'; //new url
                 audioplay.load(); //preload
                 audioplay.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
                     audioplay.play(); //playing
                 });
             });
        </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

change this

```
audio.src='audio/ogg/' + document.getElementById(song1.ogg);
```

to

```
audio.src='audio/ogg/' + document.getElementById('song1');
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. Firebug is saying its getting a 500 because it looks like its passing  %5Bobject%20HTMLLIElement%5D   that in when it runs the `document.getElementById('song1');` I'm not sure what that means.